# pickadate.js is not getting my pre populated date field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, input, datepicker

i'm using the [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm) library for selection of dates in my rails app. I have a page where the datefield is pre populated. On sumbit i expect the prepopulated values to be submitted however pickadate it will always submit a default date(current date)

Does anyone have experience working with the pickadate.js library? Does anyone know the correct way to let pickadate recognize my pre populated date value? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

Javascript showing pickadate settings, notice that I also used pickatime which works well with my prepopulated time value

```
    $('#offer_valid_from_date').pickadate({format:'ddd, d mmm',formatSubmit:'ddd, d mmm',hiddenSuffix: '',});
    $('#offer_valid_from_time').pickatime({min: [7,30], max: [24,0], formatLabel: 'h:i A',formatSubmit:'HH:i:00',hiddenSuffix: ''});
```

below shows the rendered html code of the inputs with pre populated date and time.

```
<input class="form-control" id="offer_valid_from_date" name="offer[valid_from_date]" type="text" value="Fri, 28 Feb" />
<input class="form-control" id="offer_valid_from_time" name="offer[valid_from_time]" type="text" value="8:00 AM" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems with `formatSubmit:'ddd, d mmm'` in the past. Try removing that from your pickadate settings and see if it helps.

Comment: I just ran into issues where `formatSubmit` appears to clobber `rails/ujs` functionality that controls the form submit method.   Removing the `formatSubmit` settings fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of attributes to prepopulate the field **data-value** and **value**

- **data-value** is the prepopulated value that will be sent to the server and that follows the hidden format 'formatSubmit'
- **value** is the prepopulated value that will be displayed and that follows the format in 'format'

For your first input, both your format and formatSubmit are similar so just create a new attribute data-value.

For your second input, your formatSubmit is different than the format so make sure to adapt the data-value.

Answer (score 0):

add `hiddenName: true` as per the docs (http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formats_use_hidden_only)